# How to change default value after delete with Sequelize Model and NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have created a controller that in order to delete records of my Sequelize Model, but right now I am having a trouble that I do not know how to after you delete a record it must change the
`defaultValue`. Let me demonstrate my code below.

I have a User Model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const User = sequelize.define("user", {
    user_id: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    username: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    full_name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    role_id: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    is_active: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: true
    },
    created_date: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
    },
    created_by: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    updated_date: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
    },
    updated_by: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
  });

  return User;
};
```

And i have create a delete controller:

```
// delete user
export async function deleteUser(req, res) {
  try {
    const user = await User.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.user_id);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }
    res.send(user);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Server error. Please try again.",
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
}
```

Now I want to know that how to change the `defaultValue` of `is_active` into 0 after delete.

Comment: You can do this in two ways. one is instead of deleting the record, you can update the is_active value to 0. And the second one is you can use the sequelize paranoid method. If you configured the paranid in sequeliize, what sequelize does is, instead of deleteing the record. it will update the deleted_at column in database
For more about Sequelize Paranid - https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/paranoid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always do by yourself. Haizzz

```
// delete user
export async function deleteUser(req, res) {
  const id = req.params.user_id;
  try {
    const user_id = await User.findById(id);
    const is_active = await User.update({ is_active: 0 });
    res.status(200).json({
      user_id,
      is_active,
      success: true,
      message: "User is deleted succesfully",
      data: null,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Server error. Please try again.",
      error: error.message,
      data: null,
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you only want to change the is_active as I understand. So, I will suggest you to use findByIdAndUpdate query and set the is_active to 0.

**Code Example**

```
let doc = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{$set: {is_active: 0}});
if(!doc) {
throw new Error('Deletion failed');
}
doc = await User.findById(id); // it will retrieve the updated result;
res.json(doc.toJSON());
```

Note: *This process won't  delete the user from database. So, while validating/verifying the user, also check the is_active field.*